# NOT NULL constraint violation at UPDATE ON CONFLICT query

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, null, upsert

I have a table `player` with the following DDL. I only changed the column names and the order:

```
create table if not exists player (
    id varchar primary key,
    col1 boolean not null default false,
    col2 json not null default '{}',
    col3 varchar not null,
    col4 varchar not null,
    col5 json not null default '{}',
    col6 boolean not null default false
);
```

Here's the query I tried to run:

```
insert into player(id, col1, col2)
values (val_id, val1, val2)
on conflict(id)
do update set col1=excluded.col1, col2=excluded.col2
```

(Another row with the same `id` exists, so `UPDATE` should happen.)

`col3` has a `NOT NULL` constraint. (I verified that it has a value before the query.) Yet, when the query runs, Postgres tells me:

> ERROR:  ... null value in column "col3" of relation "player" violates not-null constraint

When I gave `col3` a default value, no error occurred and all the values were as they should be. But I don't need a default value.

I checked the Postgres docs but cannot find what is wrong with the query. What could be the problem?

Comment: "*update is what should happen*" - no. It's the `INSERT` command that is failing due to the not given, not defaulted, not-null constrained `col3`; way before it could be inserted to collide with the existing id.

Comment: @Bergi I suspected the same as well, but id value before is definitely the same as the inserted id value. Can insert still happen in that case?

Comment: @Bergi Or do you mean the initial insert? That was done in a different part of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

If `col3` is defined `NOT NULL` without default, the `INSERT` *must* provide a non-null value for it.

#### In depth

`NOT NULL` constraints are checked first. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-CHECK)

> When a table has multiple `CHECK` constraints, they will be tested for
> each row in alphabetical order by name, **after checking `NOT NULL`
> constraints**.

Bold emphasis mine.
You *might* try to replace `NOT NULL` with a plain `CHECK` constraint. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-NOT-NULL)

> A not-null constraint is always written as a column constraint. A
> not-null constraint is functionally equivalent to creating a check
> constraint `CHECK` (`column_name IS NOT NULL`), but in PostgreSQL
> creating an explicit not-null constraint is more efficient. The
> drawback is that you cannot give explicit names to not-null
> constraints created this way.

But **to no avail**. Either constraint is checked immediately, and cannot be deferred. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html#id-1.9.3.175.5)

> **`NOT NULL` and `CHECK` constraints are always checked immediately** when
> a row is inserted or modified (not at the end of the statement).

Bold emphasis mine.
This is the core issue.

Do one of these to resolve:

1. Define a non-null column default for `col3`.
   (Possibly add a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to do more sophisticated magic - if you know what you are doing.)
2. Remove the `NOT NULL` constraint.
3. Provide a non-null value for `col3` in the `INSERT`. You can apply or drop the same in the `UPDATE`. Like:

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO player(id, col1, col2, col3)  -- !
   VALUES (val_id, val1, val2, val3)         -- !
   ON     CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
   SET    col1 = excluded.col1
        , col2 = excluded.col2
   --   , col3 = excluded.col3               -- optional
   ;
   ```

(The same applies to `col4` in your added table definition.)